# MPAndroidChart - how to draw grid line for only max and min value in y axis(left axis)?

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to check the graph of the polonomial equation.

I want to get the maximum and minimum values ​​in the graph obtained, but grid line of y axis(left axis) like this.[Current Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqp3u.png)

Unlike the above figure, I would like to draw the y grid line of the graph as follows.[The chart I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/367UH.png)

Is there any way to display grid line of max and min value? 
I tried to solve it using the setValueFormatter function, but I do not know how to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/axis-general/

You can use **setShowOnlyMinMax(boolean enabled)**

That is used to showing min / max label